# Why Toast is not showing anything in android? It's giving Renderscript fails error

Tags: android

I am new to android. While running an application, toast is not showing anything. I am getting following in console while executing Toast line:

```
V/RenderScript: Successfully loaded runtime: libRSDriver_mtk.so
D/RenderScript: RSCL: get RSCL Script failed
D/RenderScript: RSCL: mRSCLScript.get return NULL ptr
    RSCL: failed to get RSCL script in setGlobalVar
    RSCL: mRSCLScript.get return NULL ptr
    RSCL: failed to get RSCL script in setGlobalObj
    RSCL: mRSCLScript.get return NULL ptr
    RSCL: failed to get RSCL script in invokeForEach
    RSCL: script not exist or radius not support
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7c15c83000,api=1)
```

I have spent almost 2 days to figure out what is the problem. Is there someone who has already faced this issue or who can help me out of this? Everything is working fine except this.

I have also tried by creating a hello world application but there also toast is not working. I tried in one CRUD application but I'm getting the same error.

Here is the hello world code I'm trying:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    Toast.makeText(this,"This is something",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: Are you using any render script in your app?

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J    I'm not using any renderscript. For while it was working after creating the project but after that it's not showing anything.

Comment: Check your gradle.xml files by mistakenly you added any renderscript dependency..

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J , Nothing is there like renderscript in gradle dependencies.

Comment: check if you have instant run is enabled and DISABLE IT

Comment: try the following: restart android studio ,create a new project and create a helloworld app without toast and displaying a text in textview.If its working then check with toast.

Comment: mention your build sdk version,build tool version,etc so that is increase the chance of getting solution

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J , This is in my build file:      android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.androiddemo"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: @SIVAKUMAR.J , for simple application or any CRUD application, everything is working without toast, only the problem is toast is not showing anything...

Comment: refer "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20678436/android-toast-messages-not-working".U need to turn on notification settings of ur app  as on.

Comment: In ur query the "override fun onCreate  ..." it is in activity or any other?

Comment: tick or give points to the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to **Clean** and **Rebuild** your application.

1. Check all dependencies in the Gradle (just to confirm everything is fine)
2. Run without the Toast, if it is working fine without Toast.
   then try to add a Toast

   ```
   Toast.makeText(this@YourActivity, "you are good to go", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   ```

hope it works.

Comment: it's working fine without toast but with toast, it's giving the same log

Comment: @ user10221025 u need to turn on notification settings of ur app .Then only toast coming otherwise toast not displaying

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
  Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .setTextColor(Color.WHITE)
            .show()
```